# Pizza ordering system

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there any room for improvements in this code. I am new to programming (python3), learning and practicing functions related to arguments recently.

```
def make_pizza(*toppings, **pizza_info):

    """Creating a dictionary for pizza information"""
    pizza = {}

    pizza_toppings = [topping for topping in toppings]
    pizza['toppings'] = pizza_toppings

    for key, value in pizza_info.items():
        pizza[key] = value

    return pizza



def show_pizza(pizza):

    """Showing the order with the information provided by make_pizza() function."""

    print("You've ordered " + str(pizza['size']) + " inches size " + pizza[
        'crust'].title() + " crust pizza with the toppings of:")

    for topping in pizza['toppings']:
        print("-" + topping.title())

# Taking order in a form of dictionary structure 
order = make_pizza('cheese', 'mushroom', size=12, crust='thin')

# Show the order message 
show_pizza(order)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use standard copy functions instead of manually copying:

```
from copy import copy

def make_pizza(*toppings, **pizza_info):
    pizza = pizza_info.copy()
    pizza['toppings'] = copy(toppings)    
    return pizza
```

And maybe use a dict-comprehension for merging information, instead of mutating the pizza:

```
def make_pizza(*toppings, **pizza_info):
    return {
        **pizza_info,
        'toppings': copy(toppings)    
    }
```

For printing, use f-strings for easier formatting:

```
print(f"You've ordered {pizza['size']} inches size {pizza[
    'crust'].title()} crust pizza with the toppings of:")
```

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. I gained a lot of insight from this. Gotta apply those practise real quick. :)

Comment: Maybe I answered too fast. Please note that:

- the copy function will give you the same type as the input you give it, so you will end up with a tuple for toppings, not a list (which might be as fine)
- the copies here are actually not needed, as *args and **kwargs are already created anew when the function is called
- the copies are only shallow. It makes no difference when the contents are only strings, as these are immutable, but if you had anything mutable it could cause trouble
- but if you avoid mutating anything in your programs, this will not be a problem

Comment: Thank you so much for giving me such efforts and being considerate about my codes. I will keep on working on your suggestions. Big thanks to you. :)